# Use multiple commands in sed to insert text after string with special characters

Tags: command-line, sed, regular-expression, replace

I am having a little trouble trying to do a search and replace using `sed` in a config file.

I want to use multiple commands using the `-e` option to do the following.

- Step 1: find the first occurrence of `DBName=.*` in the file at the start of a line and replace with `DBName=localhost`
- If `DBName=.*` does not exist

  - Step 2: find the first occurrence of `# DBNAME=.*` in the file at the start of a line and insert a line below the string with `DBName=localhost`
- If `# DBNAME=.*` does not exist

  - Step 3: insert `DBName=localhost` at the bottom of the file

The first occurrence syntax is tripping me up. Also the `#` followed by a "space" in the string `# DBNAME=` is also catching me out.

Comment: If a line starts with `DBName=` then `DBName=.*` matches the entire line so replacing `DBName=.*` with `DBName=localhost` means replacing the entire line. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @don_crissti, Yes that is what I am after.   
  
Step 1 will look something like this  
`sed -i -e  's/DBName=.*/DBName=localhost/' FILENAME`  
but I want it to only do this for the 1st occurance. It is unlikely that there will be more than one occurrence of this string without a preceding `#` but I want to make my bash script foolproof.

Comment: Furthermore, if your file contains both `DBName=.*` and `# DBNAME=.*`  does the first occurrence of `DBName=.*`  always precede the first occurrence of `# DBNAME=.*` ? Please add this information to your post too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sed -e '/^DBName=.*/{s/^DBName=.*/DBName=localhost/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
  -e '/^# DBName=.*/{a \DBName=localhost
  :a;n;ba;q}' -e '$a \DBName=localhost' file
```

Where:

- The **first** `-e` statement searches for `^DBName=.*` (`^` means from the beginning of the line) and if it is found, the part in the `{}` brachets is executed: This will search and replace the strings and when done, `:a` sets a label called `a`, `n` reads the next line in the pattern space and prints it. `ba` goes back to the label `a`. This all causes `sed` to print all remaining lines untouched. Now `sed` exits with the `q` command at this point and the other expressions will not be processed. So the replacement is done only once.
- The **second** expression searches for lines beginning with `# DBName=.*` and if found `a` adds `DBName=localhost` to the next line. Notice, the newline here in the command is needed, because the `a` command must not have anything after it on its line. When that addition is done, `:a;n;ba;q` does the same as in the first expression. If not...
- ...the **third** expression is processed. It adds to the last line of the file (`$`) with the `a` command the string `DBName=localhost`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will work a treat. Although, how do I tell each expression to only do this for the first string found in the file?

Comment: @ausip Sorry now it should work as expected. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/DBName=.\*/DBName=localhost/g' -e 's/\# DBNAME=.*/DBName=localhost/g' config_file
```

It will satisfy your first two conditions